# GRUB destroyed Win7 boot loader, now neither work

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, windows-7

I had Win7 on my laptop (technically still do) and I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on an unused portion of the drive. Ubuntu started up OK, but didn't work well with my wireless at work. So I tried to boot back into Windows and it won't load the bootloader. If I select the SYSTEM part (which contains a loader) it does nothing. If I select to boot from the part I know has the copy of Windows it fails with a C000000F error (File not found). I tried to repair the boot manager using the win7 dvd, but now not even GIMP is showing up. I know I can get GRUB to work again, but I think I have to repair the windows boot loader first. I'm not sure how to do that.

I know this should probably go in an "Ask Win7" SE, but I don't know of one. So if anyone can help me restore windows or point me to a good windows tech forum I'd appreciate it.

EDIT:
Here's a little more technical detail. I have an HP laptop that came configured with four drives: SYSTEM, Main, HP_TOOLS, RECOVERY. SYSTEM is what it says it is. It's actually the boot drive that loads the operating system on Main. When I installed grub I put it on SYSTEM thinking that would cause the least amount of confusion to the core boot loader. However, I realized this was a mistake early when I tried to boot to that drive only for grub to reappear. I tried to boot into Main but that caused the 0xC000000F error. I can't find a log that tells me what is causing that error.
I can (now) boot into Ubuntu just fine. Boot-Loader didn't detect a problem on any of the drives and it didn't fix anything.

RE-EDIT:
I should also probably mention that these four drives used to each be primary partitions. I changed HP_TOOLS and RECOVERY to logical partitions. I'm not sure if this is important or not, but something I read somewhere made me think it could make a difference.

Comment: You should be more specific. The issue right now is that you cannot boot into Windows, right? In that case, follow this procedure: http://askubuntu.com/q/88384/62483

Comment: Do you mean grub (pic here)http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-B0AoEoZ4qfM/T6WJZjjqrpI/AAAAAAAAANA/i4uzY9SwPAc/s1600/2012-05-04%2B21.18.47.jpg instead of gimp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So despite the lack of information I provided here I finally managed to boot back into Windows by following directions I found here:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/windows-7-after-grub-bcd-0xc000000f/4a42140a-7ce5-4c53-9c4e-9d5fd6372be9
It just starts in Win7 now, but I think I can use EasyBCD from here to get it dual booting.